# How to find the elements of a specific order in a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a cyclic group $G$ of order $16$. A generator is $x$. I wish to find all the elements in $G$ of order $8$. 
I know how to find the generators and subgroups but I'm not sure how to find the elements, especially given that neither $8$ or $16$ are prime numbers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k\in\mathbb N$, then the order of $x^k$ is equal to $\frac{16}{\gcd(16,k)}$. So, the elements of order $8$ are those $x^k$ such that $\gcd(16,k)=2$.